# Incrementing key value to save data in localstorage

Tags: javascript

I need to increment key value when I'm saving data to localstorage because when I click button key is same for all records and record just update,doesn't creating new. I know I can do this with closures bit I'm fresh in JS and dont know how to do it correct.

```
(function() {

window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('buttonCreate').onclick = function() {
        var topicValue = document.getElementById("create-topic").value;
        var statusValue = document.getElementById("create-status").value;
        var descriptionValue = document.getElementById("create-description").value;
        var key = 0;
        var storage = new Storage();
        var ticket = {
            topic: topicValue,
            status: statusValue,
            description: descriptionValue
        };
        storage.set(key, ticket);
        return (function() {
            key++;
            return key;

        }());
    }
}

})();

function Storage() {
  this._ITEMS_DESCRIPTOR = 'items';
}
Storage.prototype.get = function() {
  var fromStorage = localStorage.getItem(this._ITEMS_DESCRIPTOR);
  return fromStorage ? JSON.parse(fromStorage) : [];
};
Storage.prototype.set = function(key, items) {
  localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(items));
};
```

Comment: As a first step, you need to format your code so that it's more readable. (ex http://www.danstools.com/javascript-beautify/)

Comment: You need to store hasTicket = true or false,
if( hasTicket ) //update else put into Storage.Why not try to do so?

Comment: I don't see any closure in your code, only unnecessary immediately invoked function expressions without closure variables.. also it's not clear whether you need to increment key only during 1 session or between sessions => read the latest key in storage before setting a new key

Comment: First you do not need to wrap `window.onload` in IIFE. Second, your value of key will always be 0. You are initializing it as 0, set it and increment it. You are not accessing previously saved value. Third instead of `return function(){ key++; return key}` just do `return ++key`. Also if you want to use localStorage, you can directly use `localStorage.setItem`

Answer (score -1):

You need declare the variable before the function, to save the value and add 1+.

```
    (function() {

  window.onload = function() {
    var key = 0; //move var key to here
    document.getElementById('buttonCreate').onclick = function() {
      var topicValue = document.getElementById("create-topic").value;
      var statusValue = document.getElementById("create-status").value;
      var descriptionValue = document.getElementById("create-description").value;
      // var key = 0; remove these line
      var storage = new Storage();
      var ticket = {
        topic: topicValue,
        status: statusValue,
        description: descriptionValue
      };
      storage.set(key, ticket);
      return (function() {
        key++;
        return key;

      }());
    }
  }

})();
```