# Increment value in function

Tags: javascript

I want to increment my i value to save different value to local storage. But i always = 0, what can I do to change this behavior?

```
(function() {
  var i = 0;
         var storage = new Storage();
    window.onload = function() {   
        document.getElementById('buttonCreate').onclick = function() {
            var topicValue = document.getElementById("create-topic").value;
            var statusValue = document.getElementById("create-status").value;
            var descriptionValue = document.getElementById("create-description").value;
            var ticket = {
                topic: topicValue,
                status: statusValue,
                description: descriptionValue
            };
            storage.set("task-"+i, ticket); 
      i++;

        }
    }
})();
function Storage() {
  this._ITEMS_DESCRIPTOR = 'items';
}
Storage.prototype.get = function() {
  var fromStorage = localStorage.getItem(this._ITEMS_DESCRIPTOR);
  return fromStorage ? JSON.parse(fromStorage) : [];
};
Storage.prototype.set = function(key, items) {
  localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(items));
};
```

Comment: You call `storage.set` right after setting `i` to `0`, and between that you never increment the value. Other than declaring it to `0` each time, set it to the value of the item in the storage if it exist. Also be sure to increment and then call `storage.set`.

Comment: I have already commented on your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38279021/incrementing-key-value-to-save-data-in-localstorage) that you are not fetching previously stored value.

Comment: how can i fetch previously stored value?

Answer (score 2):

Declare the `var i = 0` outside of the function. Right now it is being reset to 0 every time to function is run.

Comment: `window.onload` is only ran once. Along with that the items in `(function() {... })()` are ran once. So I don't see what that would do.

Comment: make var i global?